# RecyclerView with multiple item height

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Help.I need a horizontal recyclerView in a recyclerView.And in some item,I need gone it;

```
protected void convert(BaseViewHolder helper, DynamicsModel item) {


                    RecyclerView recyclerView = helper.getView(R.id.rvCommentImg);
                    if (item.getImg_urls() != null) {  //if img not null
                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        String[] a = item.getImg_urls().split(",");
                        List<String> imgs = new ArrayList<>();
                        Collections.addAll(imgs, a);
                        setCommentImgs(recyclerView, imgs);

                    }else {   //if none img ,GONE the recyclerView

                        recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    break;

        }
    };
```

It works ,and display images . But when inner recyclerView was gone , its item height not change.I want a multiple item height...

Comment: post your item xml

Comment: how about using view pager if you need a horizontally scrolling view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks,I used a MultiTypeItem to solve this problems with BrvahAdapter;

```
    public DynamicsAdapter(List<DynamicsModel> data, boolean isMyDynamics) {
    super(data);
    addItemType(Constants.SHARE_VIDEO, R.layout.dynamics_share_video);
    addItemType(Constants.SHARE_GAIN, R.layout.dynamics_share_gain);

    this.isMyDynamics = isMyDynamics;
}

@Override
protected void convert(BaseViewHolder helper, final DynamicsModel item) {

    helper.setText(R.id.tvDynamicsDate, formatData);
    switch (helper.getItemViewType()) {
        case Constants.SHARE_VIDEO: //todo in R.layout.dynamics_share_video
          break;
        case Constants.SHARE_GAIN://todo in R.layout.dynamics_share_gain
         break;
    }
}
```